# Appending fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a treeview component in react where data for the tree is fetched based on the nodes expanded by the user.

**Problem**

I want to replace the code inside `handleChange` with data from my server, so that I append the data i fetch to the `tree` state. How can I achieve this with react?

The data i get can look like this:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "2212",
      "parentId": "3321",
      "name": "R&D",
      "address": "homestreet"
    },
    {
      "id": "4212",
      "parentId": "3321",
      "name": "Testing",
      "address": "homestreet"
    }
  ]
}
```

My Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 216,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400
  }
});

export default function FileSystemNavigator() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const initialData = {
    root: [
      {
        id: "1",
        label: "Applications"
      }
    ],
  };

  const [tree, setTree] = useState(initialData);

  const handleChange = (event, nodeId) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const newTree = {
        ...tree,
        [nodeId]: [
          {
            id: "2",
            label: "Calendar"
          },
          {
            id: "3",
            label: "Settings"
          },
          {
            id: "4",
            label: "Music"
          }
        ]
      };

      setTree(newTree);
    }, 1000); // simulate xhr
  };

  const renderTree = children => {
    return children.map(child => {
      const childrenNodes =
        tree[child.id] && tree[child.id].length > 0
          ? renderTree(tree[child.id])
          : [<div />];

      return (
        <TreeItem key={child.id} nodeId={child.id} label={child.label}>
          {childrenNodes}
        </TreeItem>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      onNodeToggle={handleChange}
    >
      {renderTree(tree.root)}
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

Comment: What difficulty are you facing? Could you show the actual code with the API request? (eg. `fetch(...)`)

Comment: Are you asking how to replace `setTimeout` with a `fetch` request to your API endpoint?

Comment: Yes, I'm facing diffculty replacing `setTimeout` with fetching from the API so that it maps correctly to the data structure like the `newTree`. I've made a fake backend that returns JSON: https://api.myjson.com/bins/1aqhsc

Comment: @John see my answer below and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @John are you still having issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to replace your "fake" `setTimeout` implementation of an API call with a real call using `fetch`.

In this case, it's as simple as calling `fetch` inside of the `handleChange` handler and updating your state with new items that you get back as a result.

```js
function FileSystemNavigator() {
  const initialData = {...}
  const [tree, setTree] = React.useState(initialData)

  const handleChange = (event, nodeId) => {
    const handleResult = (data) => {
      const items = data.children.map(item => {
        return { id: item.id, label: item.name }
      })
      setTree({
        root: [...tree.root, ...items]
      })
    }
    const handleError = (error) => {
      // handle errors appropriately
      console.error(error.message)
    }
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1aqhsc")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(handleResult)
      .catch(handleError)
  }

  // ...

  return (...)
}
```

This should do the trick.

Note that I've used your sample API endpoint that you've provided in the comments, so you will have to change the `handleResult` callback inside of the `handleChange` handler to make sure you're parsing out your new data appropriately.

If you'd like to see a quick example, I created a `CodeSandbox` with a button that can be clicked to fetch more data and display it in a list:

- [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-dream-7xp29?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks! This was what i was looking for